# php_mssql to php_sqlsvr syntax conversion

Tags: php, sql-server

Hi I have been given a php project to move and update. The move involved moving to a newer server which meant that an updated version of php was installed. The updated version does not support the ms sql driver php_mssql.dll and so it's replacement php_sqlsvr.dll was added. This in turn meant I needed to convert the code to use the latter's syntax.

Nearly all of the code has converted fine... in most cases I just needed to substitute mssql_ with sqlsvr_

I tried the same practice on the following bit of code

```
//ORIGINAL SYNTAX USING php_mssql.dll

$dbserver=mssql_connect("localhost","user","pwd");

$db=@mssql_select_db("DatabaseName", $dbserver);
$spname="StoredProcName";
$sp=mssql_init($spname, $dbserver);
mssql_bind($sp, "@server", $server, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 4000);
$data_values=mssql_execute($sp);
```

and ended up with

```
//NEW SYNTAX USING php_sqlsvr.dll

$serverName = "localhost,1433";
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"DatabaseName", "Uid"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pwd", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
 //Establishes the connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
 //SP for Data
$spname="StoredProcName";
 //Executes the query
$sp = sqlsvr_init($spname, $conn);
sqlsvr_bind($sp, "@server", $server, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 4000);
$data_values = sqlsrv_execute($sp, array(), array("Scrollable" => 'static'));

 //, array(), array("Scrollable" => 'static') added as I need to use sqlsvr_num_rows($data_values) later in code.
```

Unfortunately this is failing at the execute query specifically @ sqlsvr_init I think. The actual code is use as an ajax get so all I see is a 500 error.

Any ideas what is wrong. I cant seem to find much on converting these different driver codes.

**UPDATE**

I've found some documentation @ http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php
It seems there is no **sqlsvr_init** or **sqlsvr_bind**. Any ideas what the equivalents to mssql_init and mssql_bind are... looking through the commands it looks like it could be sqlsvr_prepare in place of mssql_init but not sure what would be the replacement for mssql_bind.

Comment: First of all, try to check this script standalone, not through ajax. See, what happen when you call this `connectiontest.php`

Comment: @lolka_bolka conectivity works as other conversions have worked fine. I have a feeling it's the msslq_init or mssql_bind conversion to sqlsvr_init and sqlsvr_bind that is the problem as these commands do not appear in any of the other scripts I have successfully converted.

Comment: Based on further research I have found that an equivalent for mssql_init does not exist and mssql_bind has been replaced by sqlsvr_prepare although the required parameters are different. I've tried to modify my code and have got further but now have another error which I have raised as another question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133002/php-sqlsvr-prepare-execute-error